# Переместить указатель пустой ветки на мастер без добавления коммитов

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Есть ветка, которая не содержит в себе новых коммитов, но указывает на некий старый коммит мастера. Как перенести её указатель на текущий последний коммит мастера, не добавляя коммиты в ветку? Если делать ребейз/ресет ветки на мастер, то коммиты `A` и `H` надо пушить в ветку. Можно ли как-то просто изменить указатель ветки с `B` на `H`? Другими словами, результат должен быть эквивалентен удалению ветки и созданию новой с тем же именем от `H`.

```
H <- master
^
A
^
B <- branch
^
C
```

Comment: `$ git branch --force имя коммит`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin всё равно показывает, что при пуше будут все коммиты добавлены

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin или надо remote имя?

Comment: используйте git rebase а потом force push, хотя зачем делать это для пустой ветки, если можно удалить и отбранчеваться от мастера

Comment: @JVic в моём понимании это применит все коммиты на ветку, а надо просто указатель изменить. Ветка не содержит своих коммитов, так что это должно быть возможно

Comment: при мердже все комиты попадают в вашу ветку, при ребейзе перетирается история комитов (по этому и делается форс пуш) и ваша ветка накатывается поверх всех комитов и в гите вы увидите девственно чисту ветку поверх актуального мастера

Comment: "как перенести ... не добавляя коммиты в ветку" - вы что-то недопонимаете. Ветка - это указатель, если она указывает на `H`, то коммиты `H` и `A` (как все остальные в истории) есть.  "Если делать ребейз/ресет ..., то коммиты A и H надо пушить в ветку" - push/pull это вообще отдельная история. Нужно или не нужно делать push определяется тем, в каком состоянии находится ветка в remote репозитории. Если вы локально передвинули branch вперед (фактически добавили туда новые коммиты), то очевидно, что branch в remote репо отстал, т.к. не содержит эти новые для branch коммиты и push их туда добавит